# ElasticSearch Numeric Distance

Tags: elasticsearch, distance

I'm looking for a way to make a query that would return a score.

This score would be the numerical distance between 2 numbers.

Is there a way to do this in elasticsearch ?

for example if my data looks like this:

`{
  value: INT
}`

in my query I want a default parameters (an other INT)

and as result I want my data sorted with the score ( |object.value - default.value| )

Comment: Yes, using a `function_score` query, can you share some data and show what you want to achieve?

Comment: i edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) (with `script_score`), you can achieve what you need:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": { }
            },
            "script_score" : {
                "script" : {
                  "source": "Math.abs(doc['value'].value - params.default)",
                  "params": {
                    "default": 10
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,you want something like this? It searches in the field `range` and returns all hits with `score` value between 0 and 6.

> query = {
>             'query': {
>                 'range': {
>                     'score': {
>                     'lte': 6,
>                     'gte': 0
>                     }
>                 }
>             }   }

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a way to calculate the score as a function yielding the difference between two numbers and this can be achieve with `function_score`